# v-html with conditional rendered

Tags: vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js and I really love it, but I'm currently facing a problem.

I have this code in my template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-auto" v-if="steps.length - 1 == currentStep" @click="submitProject" v-html="paymentAmount">{{model.projectSelectedOptions.length < 1 ? 'Publish without option (free)' : paymentAmount }}</button>
```

And the paymentAmount computed:

```
paymentAmount() {
  var amount = 0;
  this.model.projectSelectedOptions.forEach(function(option) {
    if (option == 1) {
      option = 19.99
    } else if (option == 2) {
      option = 9.99
    } else {
      option = 7.99
    }
    amount += option;
  });
  return 'Next : payment (' + amount.toFixed(2) + ' € <span class="price-ht">HT</span>)';
}
```

My problem is that if I put `v-html="paymentAmount"` in my button, I never see "*Publish without option (free)*", just "*Next : payment (0 € HT)*".

If I remove `v-html` attribute, I can see "Publish without option (free)" but when I have selected some options, Vue.js render "`Next : payment (0 € <span class="price-ht">HT</span>)`" (so with raw span).

How should I do it?

**EDIT:**
For the moment, I added a button with a different v-if condition, but it would be cool if I can do it in one line of code, I don't like the duplicate .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about putting all your logic inside of your computed property?

HTML part:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning ml-auto" v-if="steps.length - 1 == currentStep" @click="submitProject" v-html="paymentAmount"></button>
```

Vue part:

```
paymentAmount() {
    if(this.model.projectSelectedOptions.length < 1)
    {
        return 'Publish without option (free)';
    }
    else
    {
        var amount = 0;
        this.model.projectSelectedOptions.forEach(function(option) {
        if (option == 1) {
          option = 19.99
        } else if (option == 2) {
          option = 9.99
        } else {
          option = 7.99
        }
        amount += option;
        });
        return 'Next : payment (' + amount.toFixed(2) + ' € <span class="price-ht">HT</span>)';
    }
}
```

Comment: It's perfect thank you! How could I not think about it

Answer (score 1):

You might use a conditional `span` as button content:

```js
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn btn-warning ml-auto"
  v-if="steps.length - 1 == currentStep"
  @click="submitProject">
  <span v-if="model.projectSelectedOptions.length < 1">Publish without option (free)</span>
  <span v-else v-html="paymentAmount"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I prefer the Jns's solution but I will remember this one too